# Can't remove space between vertical elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to code an infinite scrolling monster (like endless.horse but without jQuery). But it keeps showing spaces in between elements when scrolling and it doesn't look that good. Doing line-height will just smosh the lines together into a weird blob and achieve nothing. White space does nothing to stop the spaces. What should I do?

```js
window.onscroll = function() {hello()};

function hello() {
var para = document.createElement("pre");
var node = document.createTextNode(`        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
          |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
          |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
          |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
          |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
`);
para.appendChild(node);

var element = document.getElementById("hello");
element.appendChild(para);
element.appendChild(para);
element.appendChild(para);
element.appendChild(para);
element.appendChild(para);
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>My first three.js app</title>
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#hello
float: left;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
display: inline-block;
}
pre {
padding: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
<pre> 
              _-~~~-_       _-~~~-_
            /~       ~\    :    ,  \
           '           ~   ,   |:  :
          {      /~~\  :--~""""\.:  :
           \    (... :   /^\  /^\ ;
            ~\_____     |   | |  |:~
                  /     |__O|_|_O|;
                 (     /       O \
                  \   ( `\_______/)
                   `\  \         /
                     )  ~-------~'\
                    /              \
                   :               ||
                   |  |            ||
                   |  |.======[]==+'|
                  (~~~~)       |   |~)
                  /    \       |   | \
      ~\          \___/)______/^\__|_/
        `\      //    |  |      |  |
          `\__//'     |  |      |  |
             ~~       |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
</pre>
<div id="hello">
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add got pre{margin:0;}

```js
window.onscroll = function() {hello()};

function hello() {
var para = document.createElement("pre");
var node = document.createTextNode(`        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
          |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
          |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
          |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
          |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
`);
para.appendChild(node);

var element = document.getElementById("hello");
element.appendChild(para);
element.appendChild(para);
element.appendChild(para);
element.appendChild(para);
element.appendChild(para);
}
```

```css
pre{margin:0;}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>My first three.js app</title>
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#hello
float: left;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
display: inline-block;
}
pre {
padding: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
<pre> 
              _-~~~-_       _-~~~-_
            /~       ~\    :    ,  \
           '           ~   ,   |:  :
          {      /~~\  :--~""""\.:  :
           \    (... :   /^\  /^\ ;
            ~\_____     |   | |  |:~
                  /     |__O|_|_O|;
                 (     /       O \
                  \   ( `\_______/)
                   `\  \         /
                     )  ~-------~'\
                    /              \
                   :               ||
                   |  |            ||
                   |  |.======[]==+'|
                  (~~~~)       |   |~)
                  /    \       |   | \
      ~\          \___/)______/^\__|_/
        `\      //    |  |      |  |
          `\__//'     |  |      |  |
             ~~       |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
        |  |      |  |
</pre>
<div id="hello">
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```